# Как сделать кнопку *пригласить друга в чат* в телеграме?

Tags: telegram

```
t.me/@BotUsername?startgroup=botstart
```

Есть ли альтернатива? Хочу внутри чата сделать кнопку *пригласить друга в чат/группу*

Comment: Чтобы при нажатие (в клиенте), отправляло на - выбрать кому отправить

Comment: 1) Важные замечания стоит вносить непосредственно в сам Вопрос, а не в коментарии. Внизу под вопросом есть кнопка "Править". 2) Обьясните почему Вы исчете альтернативу? Не работает что-то или не так работает с тем вариантом который у Вас уже есть?